# Selecting inner text when using find element by css selector python, selenium and create a loop

Tags: python, css, selenium, find, element

im trying to get all link text from a tag p and with a specific class. Then create a loop to find all other similar elements.

[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXWG7.png)

so far i am using this :
the value i want is in

```
    <div class='some other class'>
     <p class='machine-name install-info-entry x-hidden-focus'> text i want 
     </p> ==$0

    installations = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('p.machine-name.install-info-entry.x-hidden-focus')
```

any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "link text from a <p> tag"?

Comment: the text i want is after the tag <p and after the second class ' machine-name....'> text i want.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `.text`

```
installations = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('p.machine-name.install-info-entry.x-hidden-focus') 

for installation in installations: 
  print(installation.text)
```

Note that **installations** is a list of web elements, whereas **installation** is just a web element from the list.

**UPDATE1:**

If you want to extract the attribute from a web element, then you can follow this code:

```
print(installation.get_attribute("attribute name"))
```

You should pass your desired **attribute name** in **get_attribute** method.

You can read `innerHTML` attribute to get source of the content of the element or **outerHTML** for source with the current element.

```
installation.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i gave this a try and no errors but the file is not generated and if i create it, nothing is written to it.

Comment: Which file you are talking about ?

Comment: oh my bad its not a file, its the attribute from installation.